# chrome.system.network returning 'undefined' on ARM-based Chromebooks

Tags: google-chrome-os

I have an application that depends on the chrome.system.network call to get the network interfaces.  On Intel-based chromebooks, it works fine.  On an ARM-based chromebook, the call returns undefined.  I've confirmed this on a Lenovo 300e with an MTK processor and a CTL J4+ with an ARM Cortex processor.

Has anyone else experienced this issue, or found a workaround?

We've confirmed that we have system.network permissions.

Comment: Did you mean ARM instead of AMD?

Comment: review chrome version to see availability of api and as you said system.network permissions

Comment: Yes, ARM.  Thanks.  Corrected.